# Password decryption with known salt and dictionary

Tags: encryption

We are migrating a company we acquired a lot of kiosk hardware assets from that are in the field. Since the company was suffering, we are stuck with some issues in migrating the locations fingerprints, usernames and passwords without any implementation docs. Luckily, most of the passwords used are numeric 4-6 PIN or a common used word. I'm stuck with trying to figure out what format the password is hashed in and hopefully can decipher it from there using a dictionary for the majority of the passwords. I have the following format:

```
"password": "ce62f0002776890507c4050a3b76c064d3d24328aea52a08633b726d352532dc",
"salt": "JUQLSPOYGFURMGSDRYWIWBIWP",
```

The password above is "**password**". Hopefully this helps in finding the format.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know or do? The hash method is best retrieved form the source code. The encoding of password and salt also require guesswork.

Comment: That's the biggest issue is we don't have access to source code. We have their database info and we are migrating to our software. Luckily the hardware is the same as far as payment devices and fingerprint, but we are hung up on how to get the passwords in. I don't know much about decryption but was hoping to at least figure out the format of the password encryption

Comment: I don't think they're encrypted, they are hashed. Means you are out of luck regarding decryption. You might be able to reset passwords after some reverse engineering.

Comment: Since most passwords are 4-6 numeric passwords. If I can figure out how they are hashed could I create a dictionary of all those possibilities and check them that way?

Comment: No, the Salt is used to prevent just that. Be clear about what you want and what you can do in for example the databases.

Comment: I see. I was hoping that since they were storing the salt within the database users table that I could leverage that with the hashed password.

Comment: That there is a salt is a minor inconvenience, you can't use a rainbow table and have to  hash each one with the salt and test password, it is easy to hash with a salt 1 million per second. How many entries are there?

Comment: Roughly 2000 users across 12 locations. I hashed the known password I have with SHA256 + salt and got a match. From recommendations of your other post

Answer (score 1):

If it is a hash, looks like a hash, possibly HMAC-SHA256 from the length, you need to run a password cracking program. You should be able to recover well over 90% but most likely not all.

On my laptop I can run a 20 byte password through SHA-512 and compare in under 1us so with just a SHA-512 hash I can try 1,000,000 passwords a second.

You can make a list to check but there are already good lists, see below.

For more information see:
Password list at [SecLists](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords).
Infosec [password-cracking-tools](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/10-popular-password-cracking-tools/)
Arstechnica [How I became a password cracker](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/03/how-i-became-a-password-cracker/3/).

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the old hashing method in your new code. When the password matches (i.e. the one the partner sends) you can then store it in your new format (essentually accepting both). This saves you the need to crack the existing passwords.

For this to work you do need to know how the passwords are hashed and what formatis used, lucikly this seems to be fairly easy (Java sample):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bos.write("password".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
bos.write("JUQLSPOYGFURMGSDRYWIWBIWP".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] out = md.digest(bos.toByteArray());

System.out.println("hex = " + new HexBinaryAdapter().marshal(out).toLowerCase());
```

Produces (i.e. concatenate password bytes and salt bytes, non-iteratively calculate SHA256 and convert to hex) the expected hash:

```
hex = ce62f0002776890507c4050a3b76c064d3d24328aea52a08633b726d352532dc
```

Comment: I appreciate this! I think this is exactly what I was looking for and makes the process a lot more simple. I will try implementing this.

Comment: This shows exactly why this method of password storage is insecure and should not be used. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration (the salt needs to be saved with the hash). Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: BTW: from the single example "password" it is not possible to see how the password text is transalted into bytes, it might as well use Latin1 or UTF-8 to preserve umlauts. But must US software with such hand-made hashing methods dont bother to handle unicode correctly anyway.